# .Net Core - Inject Dependency IUserInfo from API middleware down to repository layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose I have following structured project layer like **Repository ->  Service -> API** from bottom to top, Code sample:

**Repository:**

```
public interface IUserInfo
{
    int UID{ get; set; }
}
public class UserInfo : IUserInfo
{
    public int UID { get; set; }
}
public class ProductionRepository : Repository, IProductionRepository {
    public ProductionRepository(IUserInfo userInfo, StoreDbContext dbContext) : base(userInfo, dbContext)
    {}
    //...
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class ProductionService : Service, IProductionService {
        public ProductionService(IUserInfo userInfo, StoreDbContext dbContext)
            : base(userInfo, dbContext)
        {
        }
//...
}
public abstract class Service {        
    protected IProductionRepository m_productionRepository;
    public Service(IUserInfo userInfo, StoreDbContext dbContext)
    {
        UserInfo = userInfo;
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }
    protected IProductionRepository ProductionRepository
            => m_productionRepository ?? (m_productionRepository = new ProductionRepository(UserInfo, DbContext));
}
```

**API:**

```
  public class ProductionController : Controller {
        private readonly IUserInfo userInfo;
        protected IProductionService ProductionBusinessObject;
        public ProductionController(IUserInfo _userInfo, IProductionService productionBusinessObject)
        {
            userInfo = _userInfo;
            ProductionBusinessObject = productionBusinessObject;
        }
  }
```

Now, in my Startup.cs I am using JWT token with "**OnTokenValidated**" event to grab the UserInfo information from token:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
     options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         #region Jwt After Validation Authenticated
         OnTokenValidated = async context =>
         {
              #region Get user's immutable object id from claims that came from ClaimsPrincipal
              var userID = context.Principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
              services.Configure<UserInfo>(options =>
              {
                    options.UID = userID;
              });
              #endregion
          },
          #endregion
       }
};
```

I am using **services.Configure** and try to assign the UID to the IUserInfo object, but when I debugged in my controller, **the IUserInfo always represents a null object like in constructor or api method**. I know I probably misuse the Dependency Injection in .Net core, so please feel free to guide me what would be the correct way to inject that IUserInfo into my **Controller --> Service --> Repository**, so all of them can get the actual UserInfo information!

Comment: Don't you need the registration of UserInfo to be Scoped?  I'm probably missing it, but I don't see anything along those lines.

Comment: Suggest reviewing current design choices. services once built after configuration wont be affected by attempting to add additional services during a request.

Comment: @DavidL: sorry I forget to paste that and registration would be like services.AddScoped<IUserInfo, UserInfo>(); in ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject `IUserInfo` by registering it as a service in Startup.

```
services.AddScoped<IUserInfo>(provider =>
{
    var context = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    return new UserInfo
    {
        UID = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
    };
});
```

Comment: Wow! That's an awesome solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am curious about the theory behind the HttpContext.User, I set my UID or Email or Name through Claim then assigned to JWT security token, but how did asp.net core know that the HttpContext.User also set up with the same information? And it seems I have to use "Authorized" attribute on my api so I can get the IUserInfo, if I don't have that my API will not be able to retrieve my IUserInfo which setup in ConfigureService(), so is there any connection between these? I am actually following an online tutorial but indeed I don't know the idea behind this scenario...

Comment: @KevinDing You should read the [authentication chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of the official docs. You are using JWT authentication, so before each request, there will be middleware that parses and validates the JWT token and then makes `HttpContext.User` available.

Comment: @poke: thank you so much and I will go through that to get better understanding!

Comment: @KevinDing You can bypass authorization by using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your action methods and controllers.  `IUserInfo` will still be resolved by DI but the `IUserInfo.UID` property will be null (or zero, in your case).  You would only do this when you have publicly available API endpoints that don't require knowing who the user is.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot register things with the service collection later like that, especially not dynamically for some request. The service collection is set up **once** (during `ConfigureServices`) and then frozen; you cannot modify it afterwards. If you want to make things available on a per-request scope, you can either share it as state in a request-scoped dependency, or put it on the HttpContext.

It does seem like a bad design though to pass around such user data as a DI dependency. You should consider passing that information explicitly in method calls.

Also, you should really embrace claims and use *that* directly. You can easily make some extension methods on the `ClaimsPrincipal` that allows you to do `User.GetUserId()` to get the user id from the claim, without having to put it into some custom object which you need to take care of. The user principal already is made available throughout the whole framework, so just use that.

---

Btw. note that using `services.Configure<UserInfo>()` in general will not register a `UserInfo` dependency (especially not an `IUserInfo` dependency!) but will configure `IOptions<UserInfo>` instead. But again: This won’t work in your case, since by the time the `Configure()` is called, the service collection has already been built.

Comment: thank you for your advise! Just want to confirm, so you're suggesting to get or assign the User Info through API method by using HttpContext or request object or just use User.ClaimPrincipal, correct? However, suppose I can get UID within API method, I am still stuck at how to pass it or let my service(IProductionService) to include or attach this IUserInfo to it? I don't know how to implement that by using DI from API controller layer...

Comment: Your controller has the `User` object (the principal), so you should just pass that explicitly when you want to do something for that user. Having the user get injected by DI (in whatever way) will just lock you into functionality that only ever works for the current user.